# how to auto redirect on login link click to admin page if user already logged in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, roleprovider

How to do this ...

i have a login page link above the page /// i want if user already loggedin then anybody click on loginlink then the user will automatically redirect to default.aspx ..

how to do this using vb.net ?

Comment: Can you provide some code how you implemented the login

Answer (score 1):

If user login then mentioned the session like this:

```
if(login==true)
{
    sesssion["UID"]=txtUserID.Text.ToString();
}
```

Then, after user click on the login link then check:

```
if(session["UID"]!=null)
{
    response.redirect("default.aspx");
}
else
{
    response.redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ==true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two built-in options when using Membership / Forms Authentication:

1: Use [LoginStatus](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/loginstatus.aspx) control instead of external link. It will automatically change to Logout when user is logged-in.

Or

2: Use [LoginView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/loginview.aspx) to display your login and Logout links.